# Benefit of Hydrogen Electrolysis

Tags: energy-conservation, hydrogen, energy-storage

I was considering building a simple solar hydrogen generator for fun and it led me to the question

> Does the hydrogen produced have more potential energy than the electricity used to get it?

Obvious answer here is no. Supported by [this article I found that says it has about 80% the energy](https://www.carboncommentary.com/blog/2017/7/5/hydrogen-made-by-the-electrolysis-of-water-is-now-cost-competitive-and-gives-us-another-building-block-for-the-low-carbon-economy)

Which then brought me to the natural next question.... Why?

Why extract hydrogen energy through electrolysis if we already have the electricity and we can store it in a battery?

So that's my question now.

> **What is the benefit of using hydrogen instead of electricity specifically for energy storage and usage?**

Comment: Well the manufacture of batteries depends mostly on lithium (or lead-acid), and isn't very good for the environment overall. But this will be situationally dependant.

Comment: Well, even in a local context, the need to replace batteries on a regular basis leads to issues (including the supply of lithium perhaps). In a larger context, the ability to process and transport the hydrogen as fuel makes for many options in the energy economy.

Comment: So then the short answer is easier to transport and the storage is cheaper because it doesn't need replaced as frequently?

Comment: You can use solar power  in far away places, say deserts and transport it through pipes to the place you want. transporting hinge amounts of electric energy give also losses . Batteries for big vehicles get very heavy, and need long time to recharge, so ists easier to use gas for the engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hydrogen has a much higher energy storage density than Li ion batteries being both lighter and occupying a smaller volume. This is the motivating factor behind hydrogen energy storage and usage.